# I need to save exception into database

Tags: spring-boot, exception, spring-data-jpa, try-catch, autowired

I'm middle of a middle-sized software development project with `Spring Boot 5` console application with `Spring Data Jpa.` (not a Web Project)

I'm using `entity->service->repository` structure in order to persist records.

In order to handle exceptions; I've been using `MyExceptionHandler` (which is extended to `java.lang.Exception` and created by me) that help me to format stack-trace into console. Additionally; I'm saving it into a file (exceptions.log)

I'm using `MyExceptionHandler` in all my infinite count `@Service` classes, and `XxxUtil.java` (DateUtil, EncryptionUtil etc.)

I need to save Exception content into a database table. (Message and Formatted Detail is enough for now - I've extracted formatted detail string with root cause)

Autowiring a service or a repository in `MyExceptionHandler` class produces `NullPointerException` which is expected. I need your help to bypass this step.

I'm open to your alternative solutions like "Why don't you use `SL4J` `DBAppender`" etc.

```
    try {
        //some actions
    } catch (Exception e) {
        saveExceptionToDatabase(e);
        new MyExceptionHandler("MyClass.myMethod()", e);
    }
```

Thanks for your guidance

Comment: Do you have @Component (or other Spring annotation) on MyExceptionHandler  class?

Comment: Please provide the code of `MyExceptionHandler` class. It should be possible to autowire your classes  if you annotated with `@ControllerAdvice`. Also, the method annotated with `@ExceptionHandler` shouldn't  have a final modifier.

Comment: As I noted before on a console project `@ControllerAdvice`, `@ExceptionHandler` web annotations is not proper.

I've tested simple annotations like `@Component`, `@Bean` but no use for me